# Read and then write rasterio GeoTIFF file without loading all data into memory

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio, memory

I work with large drone image raster files, on the order of 40,000 x 40,000 and above. I have a large uncompressed GeoTIFF file and I want to use `rasterio` to rewrite the file in compressed format. I can do this by loading all data into memory, but is there a way to execute this writing without loading everything to memory?

For my original file I can open it with:

```
 dat = rasterio.open("grid_001.tif")
```

Then to rewrite the file with compression I tried:

```
profile = dat.profile.copy()
profile.update(
        compress='lzw')

with rasterio.open("grid_001_compressed.tif", 'w', **profile) as dst:
        dst.write(dat)
```

This will give me an error:

```
 ValueError: Source shape (44134, 44162) is inconsistent with given indexes 3
```

This is an expected error, because when I `open` the dataset it creates an iterator or lazy object without actually accessing the data. Now, if I did a command like:

```
 dat = dat.read()
```

This will load all of the data from the file into memory, and I can an array of dimensions `[3, 44134, 44162]` that I can write. BUT, this takes a lot of memory to implement.

Hence, is there a way to perform the same operation, but without loading everything into memory? I am not sure if windowed reads would help in this case or anything.

Comment: Just a little bit off topic but I would use GDAL_Translate -of GTIFF -co COMPRESS=LZW grid_001.tif grid_001_compressed.tif with suprocess.Popen and subsequent wait(), if all you're doing is rewriting the entire raster with compression you can skip the overheads of converting objects to/from python and no longer be concerned with memory management as GDAL_Translate manages all of that optimally.

Comment: @MichaelStimson thanks for the suggestion. Yeah, that make sense, using `gdal_translate` would work. I was looking for something that was more python and less command line, but your suggestion would work.

Comment: If you want to stick to python, there's always `gdal.Translate('output.tif', openDataset, creationOptions = ['COMPRESS=LZW'])`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use rasterio's [window or block](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html) reading & writing

```
dat = rasterio.open("grid_001.tif")
profile = dat.profile.copy()
profile.update(compress='lzw')

with rasterio.open("grid_001_compressed.tif", 'w', **profile) as dst:
    for ji, window in dat.block_windows(1)
        dst.write(dat.read(window=window), window=window)
```

Comment: this is great. Thanks for the direction. Will this work for multiband rasters too? I just ask because it has `dat.block_windows(1)`. My raster is bands, so would I need to iterate over bands, or could I just use `dat.block_windows(3)`?

Comment: Assuming each band has the same block size (as per the documentation I linked to), then this will read & write all bands at the same time