# Find pixel value from GeoTIFF using latitude and longitude

Tags: python, rasterio

I know very little of geospatial data. I have a GeoTIFF with a single band that contains a value per pixel (values go from 1 to 6). Using latitude and longitude, I would like to find (i) the coordinates of the pixel and the (ii) value of the relative value.

This is what I could put together so far

```
dataset  = rio.open(tif)

long = 151.7771477
lat = -32.89674992

row, col = dataset.index(long, lat)
band = dataset.read(1)
band[row][col]
```

but I get the following error

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 17.4 GiB for an array with shape (1, 125910, 148584) and data type int8
```

Comment: rasterio seems to try to read the whole geotiff into memory and fails. In this answer to a similar question https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368875/15183 window- or block-mode is mentioned. perhaps that helps?

Comment: Thanks - I am looking at it - would you know how to combine the block window option and look for a specific pixel? I am very new and I am not sure how to combine both solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the Windowed reading functionality of rasterio as described [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html)

```python
    with rasterio.open(image_file_name) as src:
        meta = src.meta

        # My target coordinates
        x_coord = -110.8270
        y_coord = 32.2215
    
        # Use the transform in the metadata and your coordinates
        rowcol = rasterio.transform.rowcol(meta['transform'], xs=x_coord, ys=y_coord)

        w = src.read(1, window=Window(rowcol[0], rowcol[1], 1, 1))
        # Do something with your data here.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try working with the transform which can be done using rasterio too. You can put a list of values or just a single number value which I did in the sample code below.

Relevant documentation:
https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.transform.html#rasterio.transform.rowcol

Sample code:

```python
import rasterio
from rasterio.windows import Window

image = 'raster.tif'
with rasterio.open(image) as f:
    # Load metadata
    meta = f.meta
    
    # My target coordinates
    x_coord = -110.8270
    y_coord = 32.2215
    
    # Use the transform in the metadata and your coordinates
    rowcol = rasterio.transform.rowcol(meta['transform'], xs=x_coord, ys=y_coord)

    # rowcol value: (977994, 978126)

    y = rowcol[0]
    x = rowcol[1]

    # Load specific pixel only using a window
    window = Window(x,y,1,1)
    arr = f.read(window=window)

print(arr)
# Result is in a nested array
# [[[25281]]]
```

Comment: this is great but how can I return the value of the pixel?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that part of your question. I updated my answer to include the code to get the pixel value. I double checked the pixel values in QGIS and it returns the correct value for me.

Comment: But will this also read the whole file into memory? I think it will, and thus will run into the same error as in the question. Maybe we can hack something together with windowed reads. I'll give it a try tonight...

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I updated the code to include using a Window to load a subset of the raster instead of the entire array. Hopefully it works for you.